# Specifying nodes on horizontal lines

Tags: graphviz, dot2tex

I have tried several to draw a graph representing with consecutive states in a straight line, S0 -> S1 -> S2.  Then actions in another straight line below.  There are edges between S0 -> A0 -> S1 -> A1 -> S2.  Which forms triangles lined up next to each other.
[image: desired output with states and actions on horizontal lines]

I have tried to use a cluster, and rank=same for the nodes I want to align.  I also tried to use [constraint=false] and other answers on Stack Overflow.

```
\begin{dot2tex}[fdp]
digraph G {
    newrank=true;
    node[group="states"]
    S0 [texlbl="$S_{t-2}$", shape=none];
    S1 [texlbl="$S_{t-1}$", shape=none];
    S2 [texlbl="$S_t$", shape=none];
    S3 [texlbl="$S_{t+1}$", shape=none];
    node[group=""]
    A0 [texlbl="$A_{t-2}$", shape=none];
    A1 [texlbl="$A_{t-1}$", shape=none];
    A2 [texlbl="$A_t$", shape=none];
    { rank=same; S0; S1; S2; S3;
    S0 -> S1-> S2 -> S3;
    S0 -> A0;
    S1 -> A1;
    S2 -> A2; }
    A0 -> S1;
    A1 -> S2;
    A2 -> S3;
}
\end{dot2tex}
```

However the output from the graph is a mixture of states and actions on a curve.
[image: output showing curved graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like part of a LaTeX document but it wouldn't work for me; `dot2tex` is, as far as I can see, a Python script that produces LaTeX code. But I'm out of  my depth here, it seems to work for you.

What I have done - I have corrected the mistake you have made, putting the closing brace `}` for the `rank = same` instruction back into that same line, and took it out of the apparent LaTeX environment; I also changed the arrow direction for the edges showing "upwards". Then I commented out the unnecessary instructions, arriving at

```
digraph G {
#    newrank=true;
#    node[group="states"]
    S0 [texlbl="$S_{t-2}$", shape=none];
    S1 [texlbl="$S_{t-1}$", shape=none];
    S2 [texlbl="$S_t$", shape=none];
    S3 [texlbl="$S_{t+1}$", shape=none];
#    node[group=""]
    A0 [texlbl="$A_{t-2}$", shape=none];
    A1 [texlbl="$A_{t-1}$", shape=none];
    A2 [texlbl="$A_t$", shape=none];
    { rank=same; S0; S1; S2; S3; }
    S0 -> S1-> S2 -> S3;
    S0 -> A0;
    S1 -> A1;
    S2 -> A2;
    edge[ dir = back ];
    S1 -> A0;
    S2 -> A1;
    S3 -> A2;
}
```

Converting this to a LaTex document with

```
dot2tex -ftikz x > x.tex
```

I get

[image]

which I guess is what you want, or at least, what your code will produce. Your workflow may be different, but if you correct the main mistake and move the closing brace where it belongs, you should be done. Note that `dot2tex` uses the `dot` engine by default, which is what you should be doing, as rightly pointed out be @Dany.

If you want something that is close to the picture in your post, try

```
digraph G 
{
    node[ shape =none ]

    S  [ label = "" ];
    S0 [ texlbl="$S_{t-2}$" ];
    S1 [ texlbl="$S_{t-1}$" ];
    S2 [ texlbl="$S_t$" ];
    S3 [ texlbl="$S_{t+1}$" ];

    A0 [ texlbl="$A_{t-2}$" ];
    A1 [ texlbl="$A_{t-1}$" ];
    A2 [ texlbl="$A_t$" ];

    { rank=same; S S0 S1 S2 S3 }
    S0 -> S1 -> S2 -> S3

    S0 -> A1;
    S1 -> A2;
    edge[ dir = back ];
    S0 -> A0;
    S1 -> A1;
    S2 -> A2;

    edge[ style = invis ];
    S -> S1
    S -> A0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using fdp layout engine.

According to [documentation](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/dot.1.pdf),

> fdp draws undirected graphs using a ‘‘spring’’model. It relies on a force-directed approach in the spirit ofFruchterman and Reingold

In your case you need to use **dot** layout engine.

I'm not familiar with the program you are using, but wild guess would be to replace `\begin{dot2tex}[fdp]` with `\begin{dot2tex}[dot]`